# How to verify if a row exists in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I must verify inside a table if a row exists.

I do that, the response is false but the problem is the row exist inside the table.

```
 $Qcheck = $this->db->prepare('select exists(select products_warehouse_id) from :table_products LIMIT 1');

      if ($Qcheck->fetch() === false) {
        $sql = <<<EOD
ALTER TABLE :table_products ADD products_warehouse_id Int(11) NULL AFTER products_type;
EOD;
}
        $this->db->exec($sql);
```

products_warehouse_id exist inside the table, but if I write products_warehouse_id_1 I have this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products_warehouse_id_1' in 'field list' in
```

My goal is when I intall an application, I want verify if the row exist or not inside the table. if not create the row.

Comment: Please explain why you are altering a table in PHP code?

Comment: You seem to want to verify if a certain column exists, not a row.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can fix this.

First of all, your products_wharehouse_id does not seem to be spelled correctly. did you mean warehouse?

Second, you forgot to close the bracket for if ($Qcheck->fetch() === false) {

Third, UNBALANCED MySQL brackets! Here is the working MySQL query : select exists(select products_wharehouse_id) from table_products LIMIT 1. You are missing parenthesis for the exists function

Comment: I inserted more information, sorry for the error, I changed